# Docker image can not be built due to dependencies troubles

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build the follow docker container:

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.2.1 as base
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/r.txt
RUN apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt install -y python3-psycopg2 gcc python3.6-dev && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    pip3 install --no-cache -r /tmp/r.txt && \
    rm /tmp/r.txt && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists && \
    rm -rf /home/$USER/.cache
```

Contents of my  requirements.txt file :

```
Pillow
requests
numpy
fire
matplotlib
pyaml==19.4.1
yoyo-migrations==7.0.2
```

And I have the follow error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.87kB
Step 1/9 : FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.2.1 as base
 ---> 593e936de911
Step 2/9 : COPY arm/requirements.txt /tmp/r.txt
 ---> a8caed30ef3b
Step 3/9 : RUN apt-get -yqq update &&     apt install -y python3-psycopg2 gcc python3.6-dev &&     apt-get install -y python3-pip &&     pip3 install --no-cache -r /tmp/r.txt &&     rm /tmp/r.txt &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists &&     rm -rf /home/$USER/.cache
 ---> Running in aaefd0aa62b9

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

...  A LOT OF OUTPUTS  ...

Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++-7-dev:arm64.
(Reading database ... 45323 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libstdc++-7-dev_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-7-dev:arm64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-7.
Preparing to unpack .../01-g++-7_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-7 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++.
Preparing to unpack .../02-g++_4%3a7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking g++ (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package make.
Preparing to unpack .../03-make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking make (4.1-9.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdpkg-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libdpkg-perl_1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdpkg-perl (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package patch.
Preparing to unpack .../05-patch_2.7.6-2ubuntu1.1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking patch (2.7.6-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../06-dpkg-dev_1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
Preparing to unpack .../07-build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dh-python.
Preparing to unpack .../08-dh-python_3.20180325ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dh-python (3.20180325ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libfakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:arm64 (1.22-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../10-fakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.22-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.03-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-5_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-fcntllock-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libfile-fcntllock-perl_0.22-3build2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3build2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3-dev:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libpython3-dev_3.6.7-1~18.04_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3-dev:arm64 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pip-whl.
Preparing to unpack .../16-python-pip-whl_9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pip-whl (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-asn1crypto.
Preparing to unpack .../17-python3-asn1crypto_0.24.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-asn1crypto (0.24.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-cffi-backend.
Preparing to unpack .../18-python3-cffi-backend_1.11.5-1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-cffi-backend (1.11.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-cryptography.
Preparing to unpack .../19-python3-cryptography_2.1.4-1ubuntu1.4_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-cryptography (2.1.4-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../20-python3-dev_3.6.7-1~18.04_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-dev (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-secretstorage.
Preparing to unpack .../21-python3-secretstorage_2.3.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-secretstorage (2.3.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-keyring.
Preparing to unpack .../22-python3-keyring_10.6.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-keyring (10.6.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-keyrings.alt.
Preparing to unpack .../23-python3-keyrings.alt_3.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-keyrings.alt (3.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pip.
Preparing to unpack .../24-python3-pip_9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pip (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-setuptools.
Preparing to unpack .../25-python3-setuptools_39.0.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-setuptools (39.0.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-wheel.
Preparing to unpack .../26-python3-wheel_0.30.0-0.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-wheel (0.30.0-0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-xdg.
Preparing to unpack .../27-python3-xdg_0.25-4ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-xdg (0.25-4ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up python-pip-whl (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.5) ...
Setting up make (4.1-9.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-cffi-backend (1.11.5-1) ...
Setting up python3-xdg (0.25-4ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up python3-keyrings.alt (3.0-1) ...
Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up python3-wheel (0.30.0-0.2) ...
Setting up libstdc++-7-dev:arm64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up python3-asn1crypto (0.24.0-1) ...
Setting up libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3build2) ...
Setting up patch (2.7.6-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libfakeroot:arm64 (1.22-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-pip (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.5) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-1) ...
Setting up python3-setuptools (39.0.1-2) ...
Setting up dh-python (3.20180325ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libpython3-dev:arm64 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
Setting up python3-cryptography (2.1.4-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up g++-7 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up python3-dev (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.22-2ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/fakeroot.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/fakeroot-sysv.1.gz (of link group fakeroot) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/faked.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/faked-sysv.1.gz (of link group fakeroot) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/es/man1/fakeroot.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/es/man1/fakeroot-sysv.1.gz (of link group fakeroot) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/es/man1/faked.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/es/man1/faked-sysv.1.gz (of link group fakeroot) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/fr/man1/fakeroot.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/fr/man1/fakeroot-sysv.1.gz (of link group fakeroot) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/fr/man1/faked.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/fr/man1/faked-sysv.1.gz (of link group fakeroot) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/sv/man1/fakeroot.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/sv/man1/fakeroot-sysv.1.gz (of link group fakeroot) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/sv/man1/faked.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/sv/man1/faked-sysv.1.gz (of link group fakeroot) doesn't exist
Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-5) ...
Setting up g++ (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/c++.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz (of link group c++) doesn't exist
Setting up python3-secretstorage (2.3.1-2) ...
Setting up python3-keyring (10.6.0-1) ...
Setting up build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Collecting Pillow (from -r /tmp/r.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/7d/1e9c2d8989c209edfd10f878da1af956059a1caab498e5bc34fa11b83f71/Pillow-8.3.1.tar.gz (48.7MB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r /tmp/r.txt (line 2))
Collecting numpy==1.19.5 (from -r /tmp/r.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/60/3f0fe5b7675a461d96b9d6729beecd3532565743278a9c3fe6dd09697fa7/numpy-1.19.5.zip (7.3MB)
Collecting fire (from -r /tmp/r.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/07/a119a1aa04d37bc819940d95ed7e135a7dcca1c098123a3764a6dcace9e7/fire-0.4.0.tar.gz (87kB)
Collecting matplotlib==3.3.3 (from -r /tmp/r.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/b3/7c48f648bf83f39d4385e0169d1b68218b838e185047f7f613b1cfc57947/matplotlib-3.3.3.tar.gz (37.9MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-nznb3gvz/numpy-1.21.2/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
        # The setuptools version of sdist adds a setup.cfg file to the tree.
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-n5mav8gw/matplotlib/setup.py", line 298, in <module>
        cmdclass=cmdclass,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 513, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 698, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 724, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 909, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1177, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1163, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-nznb3gvz/numpy-1.21.2/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
        # The setuptools version of sdist adds a setup.cfg file to the tree.
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.
    
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.3]
          python: yes [3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)  [GCC 8.4.0]]
        platform: yes [linux]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-n5mav8gw/matplotlib/
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -yqq update &&     apt install -y python3-psycopg2 gcc python3.6-dev &&     apt-get install -y python3-pip &&     pip3 install --no-cache -r /tmp/r.txt &&     rm /tmp/r.txt &&     rm -rf /
```

Matplotlib requires python 3.7 or higher.
What I've tried. Although  my project is written in python 3.6 I changed the row in dockerfile:

```
apt install -y python3-psycopg2 gcc python3.7-dev && \
```

The error is the same. After that I tried to change the requirements:

```
numpy==1.19.5
matplotlib==3.3.3
```

But error remain the same!
I'm discouraged why does it install numpy 1.21 if I said to install 1.19

```
"/tmp/easy_install-nznb3gvz/numpy-1.21.2/setup.py"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you install `python3.7`, your `pip3` command is still linked to your Python 3.6 install (you can see this by running `pip3 -V`). You would need to install `pip` for Python 3.7, but that doesn't appear to be available as a package. Perhaps an older version of matplotlib is available that works with Python 3.6?

Comment: Yes the older version of matplotlib that supports Python 3.6 is 3.3.4. I tried to install with this version but the error is the same. It's something strange it downloads the right version of packages here is the output:
Collecting numpy==1.19.5 (from -r /tmp/r.txt (line 3))
Collecting matplotlib==3.3.4 (from -r /tmp/r.txt (line 5))
But when installing matplotlib it somehow takes the wrong version of numpy:
File "/tmp/easy_install-nznb3gvz/numpy-1.21.2/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.
Why it takes numpy-1.21.2 there is the question

Comment: matplotlib has numpy as a built-time requirement, so it is trying to temporarily install whatever numpy it requires as a build-time requirement.  You might get further by ensuring numpy is installed first.  You can install numpy typically from apt which might be easier (and same for matplotlib, if you are not particular about the matplotlib version).  Otherwise you will have to pin a lower version of matplotlib.

Comment: None of the other packages you are installing after has numpy/matplotlib as a requirement and would eventually override the specification you made?

Comment: I confirmed [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/5a4f1b675da3d17df2d77d03bceab331afcc21db/setup.py#L285) that matplotlib 3.3.3 is using the older `setup_requires` mechanism for ensuring that build requirements are installed, and all it says is `numpy>=1.15`.  When the `setup.py` for matplotlib runs, it will try to ensure that you have any numpy (by default the latest) greater than 1.15, and this is *completely* independent of what numpy version you stated in your `requirements.txt`.  This is a shortcoming with older Python packaging tools.

Comment: Best to install numpy first if you want a specific version.

Comment: I tried dockerfile:
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.6.1 as base
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/r.txt
RUN apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-psycopg2 gcc python3.6-dev python3-pip && \
    pip3 install --no-cache -r /tmp/r.txt && \
    rm /tmp/r.txt && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists && \
    rm -rf /home/$USER/.cache

With requirements.txt:
Pillow
requests
numpy==1.19.5
fire
matplotlib==3.3.4
The error is the same:
File "/tmp/easy_install-ptnuez2w/numpy-1.21.2/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.